# How to restrict fields on a route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a form to create `components` for a`page`, and this field can only be shown when the user is editing the `page`, how do I check the route on the laravel?

It would be an `if () {}` inside the field.

```
protected function formFields(EloquentModel $model): array
{
    $request = app('request');
    /* @var $website Site */
    $website = $request->route('website');

    $websitePages = SiteContent::query()
        ->where('site_id', $website->getKey());

    $inputs = [];

    $inputs [] = [
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => 'Conteúdo',
        'type' => 'view',
        'view' => 'website.pages.field-components'
    ];

    return $inputs;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what this function does overall and where are you using `$inputs` you are returning?

Comment: It returns a view with fields

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($model->getKey()) {
    $inputs [] = [
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => 'Conteúdo',
        'type' => 'view',
        'view' => 'website.pages.field-components'
    ];
}
```

I solved it that way.